# Display links in side menu when main nav links are hovered

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to show links in the side menu, depending on what link is hovered in the top nav, and display them until another link is hovered. Here's what I have:

HTML:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li class="nav"><a class="toggle" href="#">LINK 1</a></li>
  <li class="nav"><a class="toggle" href="#">LINK 2</a></li>
  <li class="nav"><a class="toggle" href="#">LINK 3</a></li>
  <li class="nav"><a class="toggle" href="#">LINK 4</a></li>
  <li class="nav"><a class="toggle" href="#">LINK 5</a></li>
  <li class="nav"><a class="toggle" href="#">LINK 6</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="sideMenu">
    <div id="sideMenuLinks">
        <ul id="menuContent" class="menuContent collapse out">
          <li><a href="#">SM LINK 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">SM LINK 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">SM LINK 3</a></li>  
          <li><a href="#">SM LINK 4</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">SM LINK 5</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">SM LINK 6</a></li>
        </ul>
     </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.toggle').hover(function () {
        $('#sideMenuLinks').show('slow');
    });
});
```

This works to just display on hover but obviously only for `sideMenuLinks`, I have more links in different ID's, so if I hovered on "LINK 2" those links would be replaced and so on. Make sense?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add a `data-*` attribute to the main navigation links like so:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li class="nav"><a class="toggle" data-menu="first" href="#">LINK 1</a></li>
  <li class="nav"><a class="toggle" data-menu="second" href="#">LINK 2</a></li>
  <li class="nav"><a class="toggle" data-menu="third" href="#">LINK 3</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="sideMenu">
    <div id="sideMenuLinks">
        <ul id="first" class="menuContent collapse out">
          <li><a href="#">SM LINK 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">SM LINK 2</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul id="second" class="menuContent collapse out">
          <li><a href="#">SM LINK 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">SM LINK 2</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul id="third" class="menuContent collapse out">
          <li><a href="#">SM LINK 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">SM LINK 2</a></li>
        </ul>
     </div>
</div>
```

Then you could get the `data-menu` value when hovering:

```
$(".toggle").hover(function() {
    $(".menuContent").each(function() {
        $(this).hide();
    });
    var menu = $(this).attr("data-menu");
    $('#' + menu).show('slow');
});
```

Haven't tested this, but this could eventualy make the menus a little bit more dynamic.

Comment: Corrected a mistake.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply :-) I still haven't got this working but it's a start, I'll update when i figure it out.

Comment: Have you found the solution yet? I'm updating the answer now, with a working example... If the answer is useful, consider an upvote :)

Comment: I did find the solution, I just came on actually to post if anyone else needed it, but your code is a lot more concise so I'll change it. Thanks very much. I did upvote but it doesn't change publicly yet :-)

Answer (score 0):

If i comprehend correctly, you have several ID's, that you only want te have shown, when a corresponding link is hovered somewhere else on the page.

So, what you could make is a bit more of what you got going. Imagine you got this HTML:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav"><a class="toggle1" href="#">LINK 1</a></li>
    <li class="nav"><a class="toggle2" href="#">LINK 2</a></li>
    <li class="nav"><a class="toggle3" href="#">LINK 3</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="sideMenu">
    <div id="sideMenuLinks1">
        <ul id="menuContent" class="menuContent collapse out">
          <li><a href="#">SM LINK 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">SM LINK 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">SM LINK 3</a></li>  
          <li><a href="#">SM LINK 4</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">SM LINK 5</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">SM LINK 6</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
<div id="sideMenuLinks2">
        <ul id="menuContent" class="menuContent collapse out">
          <li><a href="#">SM LINK 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">SM LINK 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">SM LINK 3</a></li>  
          <li><a href="#">SM LINK 4</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">SM LINK 5</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">SM LINK 6</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
<div id="sideMenuLinks3">
        <ul id="menuContent" class="menuContent collapse out">
          <li><a href="#">SM LINK 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">SM LINK 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">SM LINK 3</a></li>  
          <li><a href="#">SM LINK 4</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">SM LINK 5</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">SM LINK 6</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now you can use a simple for loop and the jQuery you already got, to get it going.
jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    for(i=0,i<3,i++){
        classname = '.toggle'+i;
        id = '#sideMenuLinks'+i;
        $(classname).hover(function () {
             $(id).show('slow');
        });
    }
});
```

I have not tested this, but its a simple, comprehensive solution. Hope this helped you!
.

Comment: Thanks a lot, still haven't got it working but I'll see what I can do from this. I did have to replace the commas with semi-colons in the for loop: 'for(i=0;i<3;i++)' if anyone else needs this.